# Find value of Sin(theta) = -0.428

Tags: trigonometry, pi, angle

I don't understand the following example from Math book.

Solve for the equation `sin(theta) = -0.428` for `theta` in `radians` to 2 decimal places. where `0<= theta<= 2PI`.

And this is the answer:

`theta=-0.44 + 2PI = 5.84rad and theta = PI-(0.44) = 3.58rad`

I don't understand the part why we need to add `2PI` in the first answer and add `PI` in second answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometrically, the solutions are in the third and fourth quadrant. The first number generated by a computer is not even in the range $[0,2\pi]$, but it geometrically corresponds to the fourth quadrant. So you can get the fourth quadrant answer by adding $2\pi$ to it. To get the third quadrant answer, you reflect the previous answer through the $y$ axis. The fourth quadrant answer was $0.44$ radians below the $x$-axis, so the reflection is too, which makes it $\pi+0.44$ radians.

Comment: "The first number generated by a computer is not even in the range [0,2π][0,2π],..." I didn't get this part. sorry..

Comment: @gmailuser The number $-0.44$ came from using a computer or calculator, with the $\sin^{-1}$ function. That isn't in the range $[0,2\pi]$ (i.e. between $0$ and $2 \pi$) as was required by the question.

Comment: But how do we know that it is 4th quadrant. Sorry I'm taking Math correspondence course, on my own. The book has very little explanation.

Comment: Or if you can point me to some useful tutorial that would be really appreciated.

Comment: @gmailuser $-0.44$ is in the fourth quadrant because it is between $0$ and $-\pi/2$. Recall that negative angles correspond to clockwise rotation from the positive $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

The sine function is periodic, so once you find that $\theta=-0.44$ satisfies the equation, so does $-0.44+2k\pi$. Here you need to take $k=1$ to get the solution in the range $0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi$. The second comes from the identity $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$. You lost a minus sign in the question. Now you are in range already so don't need to add any $2\pi$s.